# What is similar to application event(aura framework) in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

how can we communicate across the two components? Do we have an application event in the lWc framework?

Comment: You can use publish/subscribe approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce introduces Lightning Messaging Service, which allows communication across Aura, Visualforce, LWC. It's a perfect substitution for Application events and it can be used to communicate between different LWC components.

link to documentation about LMS - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel
link to component that you'll use in LWC - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation